# how to assign string array values to variable

Tags: iphone

what i am doing is sorting the labels for that i am assigning the string array to temporary string variable  as follows:

```
NSString *tmp = [labels objectAtIndex:j-1];
labels[j-1]=labels[j];
labels[j] = tm;
```

but it shows error at last line that is incomplete types in assignment
how can i solve this?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels is not a C array, it's and Objective-C array, so you need to do

```
NSMutableArray *labels2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:labels];
NSString *tmp = [labels objectAtIndex:j-1];
[labels2 insertObject:[labels objectAtIndex:j] atIndex:j-1];
[labels2 insertObject:tm atIndex:j];
```

Comment: see show a warning NSArray may not respond to insertobject:atIndex and after application will close due to "NSInternalException reason [NSCFArray insertobject:atindex]:muting meathod sent to immutable method" this will be shown inconsole

Comment: I have edited it so now the NSArray is a NSMutableArray, so you can insert Objects.